# How can I use ASP.NET MembershipProvider for Reporting Service 2010 Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Application for report viewing through a web services reference. I have a login page where I use login control with custom membership provider. After the login, the user is redirected to a page that loads reports from a web services. However the user has to re-enter the username and password in order to access the reports.

```
ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
rs.Credentials = nc;
```

Is it possible to re-use the entered login data from the login control for `NetworkCredential` so the user does not need to re-enter the login data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about Catching the credentials at login page, pass it to the report page?disregarding security issues if any.

Comment: I had this idea too, by saving the password in a session but I don't think that is a good solution.